# Finding Mother Vertex using Topological sorting?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I was going through the code of topological sorting and then I realized that can we find the Mother vertex of that Graph using topological sorting.

```
    package com.bharat;
import java.util.*;
public class GraphsTS {
    private int V;
    private LinkedList adj[];

    public GraphsTS(int v) {
        V = v;
        this.adj = new LinkedList[v];
        for (int i =0;i<v;i++){
            adj[i]= new LinkedList();
        }
    }
    public void addEdge(int v,int w){
        adj[v].add(w);
    }
    /*
    Now, what is topological sorting?
    As it says one task always comes after the second task as if the second one is dependent on
    the first
    Now how do we choose the first most task
    To choose such task we need to visualize that if that node does not have any incoming
    edge
    for ex:

Connections in the graph 
5---->0
4---->0
5---->2
2---->3
3---->1
4---->1

                    5                            4
                 /        \                /        \
                /             \         /            \
               /                 \   /                \
              2                    0                   1
                \                                   /
                   \                              /
                      \                         /
                         \                    /
                           \                /
                              \           /
                                 \      /
                                   \  /
                                     3
              In this we can choose 4 or 5 as the parent vertex as there is no
              edge coming to these nodes and all the edges coming out
              Now here we can not directly sketch the DFS as before printing
              Zero we need to print his parents which are 4 and 5;

      Now what should be the algorithm for topological sorting?
      Let' see/
      We are gonna create a stack and then Do dfs here but not gonna pop
      and print the stack elements immediately.
      First we will take all the adjacent vertices in the stack and then after
      we are gonna pop out and print the elements
      So the code implementation will be
                   */
    //Utility function of topological sorting
    public void topologicalSortUtil(int v,boolean[] visited,Stack<Integer> stack){
        visited[v]=true;
        Iterator<Integer> i = adj[v].listIterator();
        while (i.hasNext()){
            int n = i.next();
            if (!visited[n]){
                topologicalSortUtil(n,visited,stack);
            }
        }
        stack.push(v);
    }
    //Main function of topological Sorting
    public void topology(){
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
        for (int i =0;i<V;i++){
            visited[i]=false;
        }
        for (int i =0;i<V;i++){
            if (!visited[i]){
                topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stack);
            }
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(stack.pop()+" ");
        }
    }
}
/*
Here was the whole theory and code for the
 topological sorting of a graph
 */
```

This is the detailed analysis and code of my topological Sorting. I just wanted to know that is there any way that we can find the Mother vertex using this code.

Comment: what do you mean by "mother" vertex? is it the vertex that is the beginning of the topologically ordered vertices? If yes you just have to find the node which doesn't have incoming edges. you don't need to do the whole sort.

Comment: No mother vertex means the vertex of the graph from where we can get to every node of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is based on Kosaraju’s Strongly Connected Component Algorithm. In a graph of strongly connected components, mother vertices are always vertices of source component in component graph. The idea is based on below fact.

If there exist mother vertex (or vertices), then one of the mother vertices is the last finished vertex in DFS. (Or a mother vertex has the maximum finish time in DFS traversal).

A vertex is said to be finished in DFS if a recursive call for its DFS is over, i.e., all descendants of the vertex have been visited.

## How does the above idea work?

Let the last finished vertex be v. Basically, we need to prove that there cannot be an edge from another vertex u to v if u is not another mother vertex (Or there cannot exist a non-mother vertex u such that u-→v is an edge). There can be two possibilities.

Recursive DFS call is made for u before v. If an edge u-→v exists, then v must have finished before u because v is reachable through u and a vertex finishes after all its descendants.
Recursive DFS call is made for v before u. In this case also, if an edge u-→v exists, then either v must finish before u (which contradicts our assumption that v is finished at the end) OR u should be reachable from v (which means u is another mother vertex).

## Algorithm :

Do DFS traversal of the given graph. While doing traversal keep track of last finished vertex ‘v’. This step takes O(V+E) time.
If there exist mother vertex (or vetices), then v must be one (or one of them). Check if v is a mother vertex by doing DFS/BFS from v. This step also takes O(V+E) time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes But if Mother vertex exist of the graph then first element of Topological sort